# Breeze - properties of an expanded navigation property

Tags: breeze

Environment:

- Breeze 1.4.16
- Durandal 2.1.0
- EF 6.1.1

Consider the following classes `Account`, `Activity`, and `User`. Let's call it a simple CRM scenario where a user creates sales activities for an account in their portfolio.

```
public class Account 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Activity> Activities {get; set;}
}

public class Activity
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public DateTime ActivityDate {get; set;}

    public int AccountId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("AccountId")]
    public Account Account {get; set;}

    public int CreatedById {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("CreatedById ")]
    public User CreatedBy {get; set;}
}

public class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I'm struggling to write a breeze query which when retrieving an `Account`, expands the related `Activity` entity to give me the `Name` of the user who entered the activity.

The following query works, however the createdBy property of each activity entity is always null:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery
    .from("getAccount")
    .withParameters({ id: id })
    .expand("Activities");
```

Reading through the breeze documentation on Navigation Properties at: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/navigation-properties, this seems close to the  "OrderDetails.Product" scenario so I rewrote the query as follows:

This query throws an exception when I execute it.

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery
    .from("getAccount")
    .withParameters({ id: id })
    .expand("Activities.CreatedBy");
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried .expand('Activities, Activities.createdBy') if you are using camelCase or .expand('Activities, Activities.CreatedBy') if not?

Comment: also try putting the expand before the withParameters

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these changes the outcome. The same exception occurs in breeze.min.js regardless. Thanks!

Comment: Would you post `getAccount` web method?

Comment: Adel it's a simple All() method on a repository class. Are you suspecting that the server isn't providing the correct data to the query?